# From tabindex include <selects>

Tags: html, tabs, html-select, tabindex

Is it possible to tab to a `<select>` element? I am creating a rather intensive form that would greatly benefit from being able to tab through *everything* not just the text fields.

```
<input type="text" name="date" value="00/00/0000" tabindex="1" />
<select name="hour" tabindex="2">
    <option value="1">01</option>
    <!-- Blah more -->
</select>
&nbsp;:&nbsp;

<select name="minute" tabindex="3">
    <option value="0">00</option>
    <!-- Blah -->
</select>
```

Above code does not work in Firefox (at least for me).

Comment: Let me stick some code up, I seem to be unable to do so.

Comment: @Gert: Yes, I'm a *complete* idiot. I have something that doesn't work, I'm asking a question about it, I have been unable to find other resources. [This? Not working.](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_TABINDEX.html) I don't think demeaning me is helpful.

Comment: @Gert: You said *"Of course"* and that is what I meant.

Comment: Would the answers to this question help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191879/tab-to-select-input-element-in-html