# Tabbing through an HTML form on OS X, any way to force it to stop on all form elements?

Tags: html, macos

First question here, be gentle. :)

In OS X, tabbing through an HTML form, you'll find that it only stops on text boxes and lists.  I need it to stop on all form inputs (not strictly `input`s, all form elements that collect data).

As far as I'm aware this can only be configured in System Preferences under Keyboard Shortcuts, but obviously we don't have control over that...

Anybody have any ideas?  I'd hate to have write something in jQuery to solve something that seems so trivial.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like this to force Safari to behave.  The drawback is that you preventDefault on the normal navigator tabulation, which may be a bigger problem for accessibility in some situations.  But I doubt it.

```
var Tab = {};
Tab.i = 1,
Tab.items = 0;

function fixTabulation () {
    /* This can be used to auto-assign tab-indexes, or
    #  commented out if it manual tab-indexes have
    #  already been assigned.
    */
    $('input, select, textarea').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('tabindex', Tab.i);
        Tab.i++;
        Tab.items++;
    });

    Tab.i = 0;

    /* We need to listen for any forward or backward Tab
    #  key event tell the page where to focus next.
    */
    $(document).on({
        'keydown' : function(e) {
            if (navigator.appVersion.match("Safari")) {
                if (e.keyCode == 9 && !e.shiftKey) { //Tab key pressed
                    e.preventDefault();
                    Tab.i != Tab.items ? Tab.i++ : Tab.i = 1;
                    $('input[tabindex="' + Tab.i + '"], select[tabindex="' + Tab.i + '"], textarea[tabindex="' + Tab.i + '"]').not('input[type="hidden"]').focus();
                }
                if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 9) { //Tab key pressed
                    e.preventDefault();
                    Tab.i != 1 ? Tab.i-- : Tab.i = Tab.items;
                    $('input[tabindex="' + Tab.i + '"], select[tabindex="' + Tab.i + '"], textarea[tabindex="' + Tab.i + '"]').not('input[type="hidden"]').focus();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    /* We need to update Tab.i if someone clicks into
    #  a different part of the form.  This allows us
    #  to keep tabbing from the newly clicked input
    */
    $('input[tabindex], select[tabindex], textarea[tabindex]').not('input[type="hidden"]').focus(function(e) {
        Tab.i = $(this).attr('tabindex');
        console.log(Tab.i);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    fixTabulation();
});
```

It's a bit hacky, but it's quite better than telling your users to go change their Safari settings in System Prefs, lol.

Answer (score 1):

From [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159782/from-tabindex-include-selects):

> Stupid OSX Settings:
>
> [image]

You have to change this in System Preferences and there is no way to do it otherwise (to the best of my knowledge).

What you *could* try  is to write a jQuery trigger for any input that has focus, see if the "Tab" key was hit, and if so jump to the next `tabindex` element.

Comment: Thanks Josh, in my question I noted that that's a known way to fix it "locally", but what I'm looking for is a way to fix it when I don't have control over that setting, i.e. other people visiting the site.

Comment: @sean: You could do a bit of OS detection and ask the user to change the settings. You could also (as I mentioned) write something up in jQuery.

Comment: Thanks Josh.  Looks like I'll just have to end up writing that script in jQuery after all...