# tab to <select> input element in html

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, input, tabs

I have a `form`, and within it several `input` and `select` elements. My problem is that I can use tab to move between `input` elements, but not the `select` drop down menu. I tried `tabindex="2"` attribute, but it didn't affect anything.

Is there way to do this?

Here is a sample of my code. If it changes anything I'm in php, but I'm not able to get it to tab in html ether.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <select>
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option><option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option><option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select></td><td>
        <input type="text" name="location" size=17 maxlength=22/>
        </td><td>
        <input type="text" name="date" size=12 maxlength=10/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I hope I posted this right I'm have a hard time with the code.

Comment: Here is the code: <table> <tr> <td><select> <option value="volvo">Volvo</option> <option value="saab">Saab</option> <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option> <option value="audi">Audi</option> </select> </td> <td><input type="text" name="location" size=17 maxlength=22/></td> <td><input type="text" name="date" size=12 maxlength=10/></td> </tr> </table>

Comment: Edit your question to include that snippet, not in a comment.

Comment: Post your code/script (formatted) inside of your question, not in the comment.

Comment: Your code is working fine in Firefox and Chrome. Tab actually moves to the `select`.

Comment: Are you using any plugin on top of your select element ?

Comment: Maybe you should use `<label>` element for it.

Comment: @qeremy `<label>` elements won't resolve anything here

Comment: @jerome.s; yes i think your right, tables are a completely trouble sometimes.

Comment: @Josiah Probably best if you tell us what browser you are using, where is your `<form>` tag, and also if you are using any javascript or jquery plugin related to the select element.

Comment: Thanks for all the input! I have tried in several browser, Firefox, Safari and I.E. Here is the a real live example.[http://cafe.bg14.com/purchases.php](http://cafe.bg14.com/purchases.php)  Try to tab to the drop down below Grocery. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 1):

On Firefox, for example, the `select` element on your real life sample page http://cafe.bg14.com/purchases.php *can* be tabbed to, it’s just late in the tabbing order. The reason is that you are setting `tabindex` attribute for some form fields but not all. Those without the attribute will come last.

Either remove all `tabindex` attributes (if the natural tabbing order, by order in HTML markup, is OK), or use them for all fields and other items that should participate in tabbing.

You should also fix the markup, using HTML W3C validator, after deciding which version of HTML you wish to use. The page now declares XHTML 1.0 but uses unquoted attribute values and HTML5 features. This makes it more difficult to see that there are serious markup errors, like `th` elements not wrapped inside a `tr` element. (Breaking the HTML table model may have an impact on both rendering and functionality.)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code i have tested it and its working too.
I answering it based on what you are asking to do in your question.

```
<form action="#" method="post">
   <p><input type="text" name="first" tabindex="10" /></p>
   <p><input type="text" name="second" tabindex="20" /></p>
   <p>
      <select name="third" tabindex="30">
           <option value="foo">Foo</option>
           <option value="bar">Bar</option>
      </select>
   </p>
   <p>
      <select name="fourth" tabindex="40">
           <option value="foo">Foo</option>
           <option value="bar">Bar</option>
      </select>
   </p>
   <p><input type="text" name="fifth" tabindex="50" /></p>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="100" />
</form>
```

Comment: if its not answer you looking for then please post what plugins or code you are trying to achieve this.

Comment: I inserted the code on a clean html page, and it didn't work for me. I on a Mac but I don't think that should make a difference. Firefox 3.6

Comment: I don't have any plugins, here is a live example [http://cafe.bg14.com/purchases.php](http://cafe.bg14.com/purchases.php)

Comment: **<select tabindex="3" name="groceries">** this was the change i made in your html using firebug and i get it working..try to add this select box **tabindex**